# How to trigger autoupdate events in electron for testing purposes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, electron

for example:

```
autoUpdater.on('update-available', function() {
  console.log("update-available");
});
```

I want to trigger the update-available event without actually having to revert the state of my app to place where an update is available.

Thanks!

P.S. I'd use the autoUpdater tag in this post if I had 1.5k rep, sorry :/

Answer (score 3):

Answer: Electron's autoupdater module is built using the core events library in Javascript.

All you need to do is call

```
autoUpdater.emit('your-event');
```

For more information check this out:
http://www.datchley.name/es6-eventemitter/

Or just check out the node documentaion on the 'events' module. The autoupdater module uses this very same module and event emitter class. In the examples where the method 'emit' is called on an instance of the event emitter class, the same method can be invoked on autoupdater.